# data association problem with nested route with Express.js

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Suppose I want to have REST endpoints which look roughly like this:

```
/blogs
/blogs/new
/blogs/:id
/blogs/:id/edit
/blogs/:id/comments/new
```

CRUD on each if makes sense. For example, /blogs POST creates a new blog, GET fetches all blogs. /blogs/:id GET fetches just that one blog with associated comments. /blogs/:id/comments/ POST creates a new comment to that particular blog

Now everything work perfectly but the comment association with each blog not working correctly. I think my models or /blogs/:id/comments/new route create that error. 
**blogSchema**

```
var blogSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    image:String,
    body:{type:String, default:""},
    created:{ type: Date },
  comments:[{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Comment'
  }]
});
```

**commentSchema**

```
var commentSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    text:String,
    author:String
})
```

**all route related with comment**

```
app.get('/blogs/:id/comments/new',function(req,res){
    //find blog by id
    Blog.findById(req.params.id,function(err,blog){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            res.render('comments/new.ejs',{blog:blog})
        }
    })
})
app.post('/blogs/:id/comments',function(req,res){
    //lookup blog using id
    Blog.findById(req.params.id,function(err,blog){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            Comment.create(req.body.comment,function(err,comment){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }else{
                    blog.comments.push(comment);
                    blog.save()
                    res.redirect('/blogs/'+blog._id);
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**finally /blogs/:id**

```
app.get('/blogs/:id',function(req,res){
    Blog.findById(req.params.id).populate('comments').exec(function(err,foundBlog){ 
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.redirect('/blogs')
        }else{
            res.render('blogs/show.ejs',{blog:foundBlog})
        }
    })
})
```

**Error**:
[image]

I know that it's quite difficult to understand all those thing without working with it that's why I give my virtual [environment](https://goor.me/XCfXZ) where you will find my project and can manipulate it.Any kind of help will be appreciated. 
Thanks for your time.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Sir I updated my question. Look when I added a new comment from /blogs/:id/comments/new it didn't populate with blog rather than showing empty text and author. If you need more information then please comment. Thanks again

Comment: Maybe changing `blog.comments.push(comment);` to `blog.comments.push(comment._id);` will help.

Comment: Let me check @CuongLeNgoc Sir

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Sir same problem. Showing empty text and author :)

Comment: "empty text and author" in your show.ejs view? Is it still emty on reload?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Yes it is still emty on reload. One more thing I noticed that in my db if I check db.comments.find() there also empty text and author strange!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199783/discussion-between-cuong-le-ngoc-and-emonhossain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `req.body.comment` is `{title:'emon',body:'new comment'}`. That's not fit with what defined in `commentSchema`. Change it to fit the structure of schema will solve the problem.